# switching timeline frames in logic editor (help)

Tags: game-engine, interface, logic-bricks

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33571

I have setup 3 cubes and a camera ,the camera has 3 set frames on the timeline that move to each of the 3 cubes.

what i want is to be able to use the scroll wheel of the mouse in BGE and toggle between thoughs 3 frames.

how can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a mouse sensor to run an action. In the action actuator you can specify the start and end frame to play. You will need a property to track where you are and run a different part of the action for each value.

Personally I wouldn't use the action keyframes, I would use a simple motion for the camera.

[image]

When a mouse wheel up event happens and the location property is less than 4, the camera is moved 10 units on X and adds 1 to the location property. Simply repeat for the opposite direction.

Comment: Ok here is my problem with what you said i tried following based off your picture and i dont know how to get the location property you have.

Comment: can you please or someone else explain this further?

Comment: `location` is a game property, you can add game properties to the side of the logic editor, if the properties aren't visible press N

Comment: yes but all i see is timer,string ,float,integer,boolean

Comment: so is there suppose to be more like location?